# Group by with where clause with having count equal to 1

Tags: mysql, group-by

Objective: Find all rows where (1) the number of messages for a number is 1, and (2) the length of the message is less than 5 characters in length. I can do each separately, but having difficulty when I combine the two conditions in one SQL query.

```
Sample Database Table:
+-----+----------+----------+
| id  | number   | message  |
+-----+----------+----------+
|   1 |      100 | Test     |
|   2 |      100 | Testing  |
|   3 |      100 | Testing  |
|   4 |      200 | Test     |
|   5 |      201 | Test     |
|   6 |      201 | Test     |
|   7 |      250 | Testing  |
|   8 |      251 | Test     |
|   9 |      300 | Testing  |
|  10 |      300 | Testing  |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Should just return rows 200 and 251. Tried the following, but no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE LENGTH(message) < 5 GROUP BY number HAVING count(*) = '1'
```

Returns rows but rows contains counts > 1.

Comment: [your query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9221b/2) works good . whats wrong ?

Comment: Typo in SQL query. I edited as should be 5 instead of 60 for length.

Comment: have you looked the demo ? it works good , whats wrong ?

Comment: Do a SELECT id, number, LENGTH(message) from reports - I will be interested to see what MySQL sees as the string (and how is message defined? what variable type?) length.

Comment: Yes, it only returns a number once, but I need to only return numbers who have only one message attached to that number AND where the message length of that one message is less than 5.

Comment: SELECT id, number, LENGTH(message) FROM reports

produces first three results like this:

    id          number Ascending  LENGTH(message)
    211  000-000-0000          114
    6459  000-000-0000           5
    8116  000-005-7711           5

I need query that only outputs the 3rd row in this example.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Thinking I may need to nest SELECTs, and use IN.

Comment: I just created your db and ran your exact SELECT and it only returned 200 and 251. What version of MySQL? Maybe your database is corrupted.

Comment: PPS - I also ran it with HAVING COUNT(*) = '2' and it correctly returned 100 and 201. and = '3' returned no rows because there are none in your example data.

Comment: @user3741598 I changed the id=3 row. Now 100 is returned even though there are 3 rows with same number (100). Should not be returned since number rows for number is > 1 even though one row for that number has a message < 5.

Comment: Not with mine - the SELECT still returns 200 and 251. Please re-create a new table: create table newreport (id int not null primary key, number int not null, message varchar(36) not null) then insert your 10 rows and re-run the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I made the wrong change a few hrs ago - this time I have the data just like yours. Ah, and NOW I see what you're having a problem with. You don't understand the order MySQL interprets your SELECT; it's first doing the WHERE to limit the results THEN it does the GROUP BY. Working as designed.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thanks. What I did is to edit the PHP script to create a temp table which is populated with rows where message has number count equal to 1. Then, execute second query on temp table to display rows where message length < 5. Works. Not the best or most elegant solution, but does the trick. The table is small in size, and the script is a back-end admin script - this routine rarely executed, so no worries regarding load issues on mySQL server.